# fullscreen and no toolbars, scrollbars etc. with javascript. NOT window.open

Tags: javascript, browser

How do I make the window I am standing in fullscreen and remove all toolbars etc. ?

Comment: You can't do this (in a way that will really work for all browsers).

Comment: That's diabolical and potentially dangerous. Why would you want to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What everyone else is saying: you can't do it reliably.  The closest is the window.open controls as [described here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp) but even those are often shut off by default in some browsers.

Even if you find a way to do it, rest assured that it will be abused by spammers and shut down down soon after-- it's a significant security hole.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that. You can only control (to some extent) which window components are visible for a window that you open using `window.open`.

Answer (score 0):

Ask your visitors to press F11 ;-)

Seriously, that isn't possible and should be avoided anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Internet explorer supports "[kiosk mode](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/154780)". This may be what you want. I've used it on a few touch-screen applications and it works well for this purpose.